How to get verbose error messages about "circular equalities" in OMPython?
I have a modelica file (similar to the one in this question) which fails to simulate. Here it is for reference:
circuit.mo
model circuit
    Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Resistor Resistor_2(R = 1);
    Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.ConstantVoltage ConstantVoltage_3(V = 1);
    Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Resistor Resistor_4(R = 1);
    Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Inductor Inductor_5(L = 1);
    Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.SineVoltage SineVoltage_6(V = 1, f = 1, phase = 1, offset = 0);
equation
    connect(Resistor_2.n, ConstantVoltage_3.p);
    connect(ConstantVoltage_3.n, Resistor_4.p);
    connect(Resistor_4.n, Inductor_5.p);
    connect(Inductor_5.n, SineVoltage_6.n);
    connect(Resistor_2.p, SineVoltage_6.p);
end circuit;

I try to run it from Python with code like this:
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
cmds = ['loadFile("circuit.mo")',
        'simulate(circuit)']
for cmd in cmds:
    omc.sendExpression(cmd)

Then I find the log file in the current directory and parse it to check for errors.
This code works OK with correct .mo files. But for this one, no log file is even created.
When I run this file with omc -u circuit.mo, I get a verbose error message about "circular equalities":
Error processing file: circuit.mo
Notification: Automatically loaded package Complex 4.0.0 due to uses annotation from Modelica.
Notification: Automatically loaded package ModelicaServices 4.0.0 due to uses annotation from Modelica.
Notification: Automatically loaded package Modelica 4.0.0 due to usage.
Error: Internal error Circular Equalities Detected for Variables:
----------------------------------
Error: Internal error IndexReduction.pantelidesIndexReduction failed! Found empty set of continuous equations. Use -d=bltdump to get more information.
Error: Internal error Transformation Module PFPlusExt index Reduction Method Pantelides failed!

# Error encountered! Exiting...
# Please check the error message and the flags.

Execution failed!

I would like to be able to get such messages in my Python code.
However, If I run it in OMShell-terminal, the only error message I get is Failed to build model: circuit.
>>> loadFile("circuit.mo")
true

>>> simulate(circuit)
record SimulationResult
    resultFile = "",
    messages = "Failed to build model: circuit"
end SimulationResult;

>>> translateModel(circuit)
false

>>> buildModel(circuit)
{"",""}


I also tried adding getErrorString() after each of these commands, but it always returns an empty string.
Back in the Python code, I tried saving the return values of sendExpression() and parsing them, but that gives me the same messages as in OMShell.
So, is it possible to get that verbose error message (as in omc) through OMPython?

This answer was suggested by arun3688 in https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/discussions/12265
The correct way is to use the newer API - ModelicaSystem class, for example:
import os
from OMPython import ModelicaSystem
mod = ModelicaSystem(os.path.abspath('circuit.mo'), 'circuit')

It prints the verbose error message. This was tested with OMPython==3.5.1.
